# I'm looking for info on a book just called "Horror"

Tags: story-identification, horror

My teacher had a big hardcover book in his class just called "Horror," which was *about* horror movies. The book was made in the 80s (I think,) but of course it's impossible to find any info on, because of the simple title. It had an all-black cover & fire-colored letters.

Any help or info would be awesome!! :-)

Comment: Did you happen to read this book also? Or part(s) of it? It was a book *about* the Horror genre, but do you remember it mentioning any specific works within it?

Comment: One of these, perhaps; http://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/adv_search_results.cgi?USE_1=title_title&OPERATOR_1=exact&TERM_1=Horror&CONJUNCTION_1=AND&USE_2=title_title&OPERATOR_2=exact&TERM_2=&CONJUNCTION_2=AND&USE_3=title_title&OPERATOR_3=exact&TERM_3=&ORDERBY=title_title&START=0&TYPE=Title

Comment: Can you also tell us what you've tried? E.g. what books it may *not* be? Where have you looked? etc.

Comment: One of these, perhaps? https://openlibrary.org/search?title=horror

Comment: Is this a non-fiction book? Do you remember if it was a monography or edited from multiple authors? Does it have many pictures in it, eg. screencaps from movies? What language is it written in? Are the fire-colored letters on the cover, or headings in pages, or the body text too? You may check http://meta.scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/9335/how-to-ask-a-good-story-id-question for more hints about how to improve your question.

Answer (score 7):

Could it be [Horrors!](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/087951325X) by Drake Douglas?

Here's how Amazon describes it:

> This acclaimed history of the horror genre, now expanded to include more than 75 vintage film stills, tells the awful truth about the monsters, vampires, werewolves, zombies, phantoms, and mummies of literature--and how they went Hollywood

It was published in 1989 and has a black cover with white and red letters.

[image]

Comment: I think it was just called "Horror" ...the description sounds good though. It was like the size of a Guiness Records book)... this wasn't the cover though... i will check if i can thank you :-) ...it was more about movie monsters than literary ones